# Collect list of stateFLow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

I have a list of integer state flows.

```
listOfFlows : List<StateFlow<Int>>
```

And i need a single state flow that would be a sum of the list state flows.

```
sum: StateFlow<Int>
```

How i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [combine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) to create a flow that emits the sum of all current values of the source flows each time one of them emits:

```kotlin
val sumFlow = combine(stateFlows) { it.sum() }
```

And if you really need a `StateFlow` as a result, you can use `stateIn`:

```kotlin
val sumFlow = combine(stateFlows) { it.sum() }
val sumStateFlow = sumFlow.stateIn(someScope)
```